# Is it possible to set 4tds in first row and 3 tds in second row

Tags: html

I am new to HTML and CSS designs. I have the below code.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">&#160;</td>
            <td width="25%"></td>
            <td width="25%"></td>
            <td width="25%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >wqewqehkjfoiw</td>
            <td >abcdefdsfds</td>
            <td >sdfdsfdsfdsf</td>
            <td >dsfsdfdsfdsfsdweqw</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="34%">wqewqehkjfoiw</td>
            <td width="33%">abcdefdsfds</td>
            <td width="33%">sdfdsfdsfdsf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The first and second rows have 4 tds of equal width. Now on third row, i wanted to have 3tds with equal width. But it is not working with the above code. Pls help

Comment: I have to go out now but you can do this using empty columns - I'll add a solution later if no-one else has (http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/258530.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using a grid system (like http://960.gs/) instead of tables.

If you still want to use tables, use the `colspan` attribute:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" width="25%">&#160;</td>
            <td colspan="3" width="25%"></td>
            <td colspan="3" width="25%"></td>
            <td colspan="3" width="25%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" width="33%">wqewqehkjfoiw</td>
            <td colspan="4" width="33%">>abcdefdsfds</td>
            <td colspan="4" width="33%">>sdfdsfdsfdsf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The table above has 12 columns, so for `N` `td`s, use `colspan="12/N"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table width="100%" border="5">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="25%">&#160;</td>
            <td colspan="25%"></td>
            <td colspan="25%"></td>
            <td colspan="25%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="25%">wqewqehkjfoiw</td>
            <td colspan="25%">abcdefdsfds</td>
            <td colspan="25%">sdfdsfdsfdsf</td>
            <td colspan="25%">dsfsdfdsfdsfsdweqw</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="34%">wqewqehkjfoiw</td>
            <td colspan="33%">abcdefdsfds</td>
            <td colspan="33%">sdfdsfdsfdsf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you tried won’t work because it does not correspond to the HTML table model, or any logical table structure. What browsers do in practice is (as you probably noticed) that they treat the row with three cells as if it had a fourth, empty cell. And then they more or less ignore the conflicting width settings.

Among the possible workarounds, the cleanest (and most common) is probably the use of nested tables. You would replace the last row cells by a single cell that spans all the four columns and contains an inner one-row table. The last row could thus be:

```
   <tr>
        <td colspan=4>
          <table width=100%>
            <tr>
              <td width="34%">wqewqehkjfoiw</td>
              <td width="33%">abcdefdsfds</td>
              <td width="33%">sdfdsfdsfdsf</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```